# How do I use parallax to scroll through my content?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, parallax, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have some issues with parallax for android, where I currently have an image on top (with text content in the center) and a button on the top right.
Now as I scroll, I want the text and button to remain fixed on screen. As I scroll past the appbar (toolbar), the toolbar should be fixed to the top and the button should be on top right of it, fixed to it , while the rest of the content stays scrollable. 
Here's my code (without parallax), any clue how i can achieve this ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cl_root_view"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                style="@style/Toolbar"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:contentInsetStart="5dp"
                android:contentInsetLeft="5dp"
                android:contentInsetEnd="5dp"
                android:contentInsetRight="5dp"
                app:contentInsetEnd="5dp"
                app:contentInsetLeft="5dp"
                app:contentInsetRight="5dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="5dp"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                        style="@style/Toolbar.AltTitleText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_dots"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/my_button"
                        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="@+id/toolbar_title"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_my_button"
                        android:tint="@color/black" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFFFFF">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/roomsTitle"
                    style="@style/Headline2LeftBlack"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnMore"
                    android:paddingStart="20dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/meeting_rooms"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Chronicle"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnMore"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.02"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="2sp"
                    android:paddingStart="20dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/all_rooms"
                    android:textColor="@color/reddish"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/roomViewPager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="400dp"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:overScrollMode="never"
                    android:paddingStart="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="16dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="45dp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/roomsTitle" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/register_a_visitor_container"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/roomViewPager">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/register_visitor_icon"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:tint="@color/reddish"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_register_visitor_icon"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/register_a_visitor_button"
                        style="@style/Body1RegLeftBlack"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:letterSpacing="0.01"
                        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/register_visitor_icon"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
                        android:text="@string/register_a_visitor"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Text.Roboto.Regular" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/reset_password_chevron"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:tint="@color/brownish_grey"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_baseline_chevron_right_24px"
                        />


                </RelativeLayout>
                <!-- TODO work on it after MVP -->
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/container">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/upcoming_events"
                        style="@style/Headline3LeftGrey"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                        android:text="@string/upcoming_events" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/event_recycler_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/upcoming_events"
                        android:background="@color/black"
                        tools:listitem="@layout/item_repo_view" />
                </RelativeLayout>

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

As you can see from the above layout. I want to add an image (and add the my_button on top right of that image) that is above the toolbar and scrolls off the screen as you scroll up while my button stays in its place until the toolbar gets on top ,after which the toolbar is affixed to the top as you scroll further up, unless you scroll down and the image is visible again and the button is no more fixed. 
Please let me know if this is confusing,I will try to explain it better with diagrams if possible.
Any examples will be helpful! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code, i have made something like you.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/view_profile_parent_layout"
android:background="@color/splash_bg_color"
tools:context=".view_profile.ViewProfileActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_barLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/view_profile_profile_app_bar_height"
    android:elevation="@dimen/view_profile_app_bar_elevation"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:titleEnabled="false"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/view_profile_imageView"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/view_profile_profile_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/view_profile_profile_height"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_profile_icon"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:civ_border_width="@dimen/view_profile_profile_border_width"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/textPrimary"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/view_profile_profile_name_textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/view_profile_profile_name_margin_top"
            android:layout_below="@id/view_profile_imageView"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="@dimen/view_profile_profile_name_text_size"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:elevation="@dimen/login_btn_elevation"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            android:contentInsetLeft="0dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/back_button"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/back_btn_layout_w"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/back_btn_w"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/back_btn_w"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_padding"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp"
                    android:elevation="@dimen/login_btn_elevation" />

            </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/nav_outer_h_space"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                    android:text=""
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/title_size" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/edit_button"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/back_btn_w"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/back_btn_w"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/nav_outer_h_space"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_white_icon"
                    android:elevation="@dimen/login_btn_elevation" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Use

> app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll"

in collapsing layout

> app:layout_collapseMode="pin"

in Toolbar